# jQuery selector from parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a `ul` element that has `li` items inside it. The `li` items do not have any attribute set that I can use as a direct selector (no class set, no id, and no way to set these). Based on the value of a link inside a particular `li`, I want to hide the element. So in the example below, I want to set the css of the `li` with the `href='link4'` to hidden.

How would I write the selector to grab this element? I've tried many variations including `has([href='link4']), which I thought would work, but with no luck.

Thanks for help.

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li><a href="link1">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3">link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="link4">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @PSR-- sorry, what are you asking? Is the question not clear enough?

Comment: @PSR: It's clear enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylist li').has('a[href=link4]').hide();
    //  $('#mylist li:has("a[href=link4]")').hide();
    //  $('#mylist li).eq(3).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LQdnG/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$("#mylist li:contains('link4')").hide();`

Comment: I think this will only find links that have the text "link4" in between the opening and closing `<a>` tags.  See the API docs here: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Using has you can do that,

```
  $('#myList li').has('a[href=link4]').hide()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var anchor4=$('#mylist li a[href="link4"]')
```

you'll get object of a tag in above variable.to hide its first parent li,you can do this.

```
$(anchor4).closest('li').hide();
```